What does the filename "gmon.out" stand for?
The GNU compiler toolset has a profiler "gprof" for performance analysis of C++ programs. With the -pg switch, the gcc compiler will make executables that write a data file, "gmon.out", on each run. This can then be fed into the gprof tool for analysis. (A prior question asks about that process, here.)
Usually I can decode the abbreviation or acronym to which these command-line tools refer. For example, "gprof" apparently stands for the "GNU profiler". However, I'm coming up empty for an explanation on what the token "gmon" means.
What's the origin/etymology of the abbreviation or acronym to which "gmon.out" refers?

Stack Overflow is narrowly focused on practical questions -- that is to say, questions expected to have answers that impact how you go about the practice of software development. What specific problem encountered in the practice of software development would an answer to this let you solve?
